# Change made in developer tools remains after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I inspected an element on the webpage through Chrome dev tools. I added to the styling: "font-weight:normal". I didn't mean for it to be permanent but now the change won't go away. It remains after refreshing. So whenever I inspect the element, that element isn't bolded like it's supposed to be. But when I got to the actual file in my source code, there's no "font-weight:normal" code.

What's going on? Why is the change remaining? How can I revert changes?

Comment: You haven't made any changes. Either the browser cached the page or you're mistaken about the change you think you made.

Comment: `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`R` clears the cache and does a "hard reload". I use this shortcut all the time when working on frontend problems. I'm not saying you have a cache problem here, just wanted to point out a useful tip ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your browser cache. And open and close your dev tools.

Comment: I cleared my browser cache, but problem remains. 

When I inspect the element this is what shows up:
#container_challenge_topic #display-region #ct-display h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 20px 0 25px;
    line-height: 125%;
    max-width: 70%;
    font-weight: normal;
}

But when I got to the actual file this code is in, this is the code:
            h3{
                font-size:16px;
                margin:20px 0 25px;
                line-height:125%;           
}

where is the browser pulling its code from? bc it's not the actual file.

Comment: I see the font-weight is normal?

Comment: yeah i misspoke earlier. I eventually want the element to not be bolded. I want the font-weight to be normal. But it was bolded previously bc it is a header. So I played with the styling within browser tools and added the 'font-weight: normal' to the styling. it immediatelyfixed the problem. But now I want to make permanent changes in the code to fix it, so the change doesn't just show on my webpage. but it's hard to see result of changes i make in actual files of code bc for some reason the "font-weight:normal" i added through the dev tools is now permanently there.

Comment: In chrome's dev tools next to the style, it should say where that style is coming from. e.g. the name of the .ccs file. or nothing if the style was made inline.

Comment: Yes, the file to the right of the styling is a .scss file. However, that .scss file doesn't make the font-weight normal. However, there is a .css file which does have the 'font-weight normal' code. I guess the code from this .css file is actually what's being loaded in the browser

Comment: That sounds correct, is this .css file different from what you see when you inspect the element in the dev tools?

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved. I guess I had compiled my SCSS file into a CSS file where the "font-weight:normal" was saved. So when I was trying to change my SCSS file and didn't see changes in the webpage, I was confused. However, when I recompiled the SCSS file into CSS, I see that everything it working as it should and the browser reflects correct code changes as I recompile.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to open in a new tab and see if the changes stick

2) You are saying your source code doesn't reflect this change- make sure you the browser is loading the file you are editing (maybe you made a copy of it?)

Comment: The changes stick even in a new tab. How do I make the the browser is loading the correct file?

Comment: @coderk isn't the file path is in the chrome url (above)- Or you can just delete your entire file (ctrl - x) and see if something changed